# wx/setup.h file not found on XCode 4

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion, wxwidgets

i'm trying to make work **wxWidgets on OS X 10.8 with XCode 4**. So far i've managed to build the library in static mode.

I'm currently trying to add the library to a basic "hello world" sample project.
For that, i follow a tutorial that explain step by step the process.

I'm stuck though on a simple error : **can't find "wx/setup.h"**

i've check the **derivedData** folder where is the .a library and there is **no setup.h**

I had one setup.h created when i compiled wxWidgets using the Terminal (but i had other errors this way after, so i had to switch to XCode wxWidgets generation.)

*where is the generated **setup.h** when building wxWidgets from XCode ? and how do i tell the compiler to use it?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never compiled wxWidgets under OS X using Xcode so I can't help you with finding the file (however I do wonder if you tried `find . -name setup.h` or using Spotlight?), but I can guarantee that the library compiled from the command line is compatible with the applications built using Xcode, *provided* you use the same compiler and runtime library for both. So if you already have a version built from the Terminal, you really should be able to just use it.